# WPF without Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf

Would it be practical to create WPF applications without ever touching Visual Studio (or any other IDEs)? As in, coding and compiling completely within Vim and the command-line? What resources would you recommend for someone trying to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be **possible**, since basically WPF is based on XAML - a variant of XML - and C# or VB.NET or another .NET language as its backend language.

The question really is whether that's **practical** and if it makes sense - I highly doubt it. WPF is all about visual design, e.g. totally without a visual designer (either the built-in one in Visual Studio, preferably the 2010 version; or some other visual designer), it seems a bit silly to want to program WPF....

As for resources - well, a least a text editor is a must, then definitely a few good books on WPF, and you could leverage the C# or VB.NET compiler that comes with the .NET framework.

Comment: Plus it's really hard to get the details right and without a visual designer, the edit-compile-test cycle would get painful.

Comment: Your Expression Blend link is broken.

Comment: This answer seems wrong to me, from my experience programming Android; which is also geared towards GUI ease of development like C#. All my Apps were created without a designer, on my mobile phone using a simple text editor and AndroidBuilder or AIDE. It is not that hard to sketch a UI design in your head or on paper and align it in pixels.

Answer (score 9):

I have found myself writing XAML in Notepad on a number of occasions where I needed to create a quick UI but couldn't load an IDE.  It is really quite trivial, and almost - but not quite - as fast as using an IDE.  The main advantages of an IDE such as Blend or VS.NET are in quickly getting things like colors and animations to be "just right."

Another occasion when I frequently write XAML or C# in a text editor is here on Stack Overflow.  I only fire up Visual Studio when I need to test something out.

My main recommendations for creating WPF applications without an IDE are:

First you should make proper use of WPF's layout system, using appropriate panels and "Auto" sizing wherever possible.  For example, if you want a stack of buttons with some space between them, create a `<StackPanel>`, and on each button add `Margin="4"` or whatever.  This is good design anyway.  Most beginning WPF programmers treat it like WinForms with no layout capability, which is a shame.  WPF has a very powerful layout engine and it should be used.  If it is, there will never be any need for graph paper or measurements.  In addition, your UI will automatically adjust its layout if you change font sizes or objects are larger than expected.

Second you should use msbuild for your project unless it is ultra-simple.  msbuild is installed along with NET Framework so it is always available.  The file format is very easy to edit with a text editor, and it is much better than a batch file with the appropriate "csc" command because it allows you to use code-behind and is less error-prone when adding new source files.

Third keep a PowerShell command line window open separate from your editor, with a command that runs "msbuild" and then executes your application.  To run your app, then just Alt-Tab to this window and hit uparrow, Enter.  Some text editors have the ability to execute user-defined commands directly from within the editor and see the output, in which case this second window is not necessary.

Fourth keep a copy of cordbg or mdbg handy.  Although an IDE is the ideal place to do your debugging, any debugger is better than none at all.  You will find your problems much faster if you stop at breakpoints and examine variables than if you just keep editing code and re-running.

Fifth, use "ColorPad" or a similar application to select your colors for use.  Just guessing and entering your best guess in hexadecimal just doesn't work very well.

For resources, I recommend you get the book "WPF Unleashed" and work through the examples.  I would also read a lot of other people's XAML, such as can be found on CodePlex.

Answer (score 5):

Possible, Yes. Practical No.

For production work, I would consider Microsoft Expression Blend 3. Then copy the XAML and paste it into the editor of your choice and compile from the command line.

You could download [KAXAML](http://www.kaxaml.com/) . It's a free, lightweight editor. I found it good for learning about XAML and seeing how minor changes and tweaks can impact on an overall design.

XAML is plain old text so find a free editor (KAXAML), use it, and if you must, paste into your editor.

Comment: Doesn't Blend count as an IDE though?

Comment: Sure but I also prefaced it with "For production work." If someone wants to use text editors and graph paper, feel free. If you're gonna do XAML and want to be productive you really need to look at an IDE.

Comment: I am assuming gamedevv is doing this for learning purposes as (going out on a limb here) no company would ever expect developers writing production code to write XAML with just a text editor. You are more productive with an IDE.

Comment: @Scott - I wouldn't want to design production code in anything other than an IDE. It would give you an insight into the syntax and structure though.

Comment: WARNING do not click the link in this answer. It goes to a site that is absolutely NSFW.  I really hope I don't get in trouble for this.  Perhaps it used to link somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to go down this route, I'd recommend getting some graph (squared) paper and a sharp pencil.

Draw out your designs on that, read off the positions and type them into your editor of choice.

One benefit of this is that you're going to have a paper prototype to show people ;)

As [James Keesey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18295/james-keesey) points out in his comment on [marc_s's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marcs) answer, your edit-compile-test cycle is going to be painful.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible. I'd say it's not practical, though.

To be honest, I do professional WPF development and I do it with the visual designer closed. I'm much more comfortable editing the XAML by hand, just like I write HTML. However, the benefits of an IDE go far beyond the visual designer. There's [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense), debugging and a whole host of other invaluable features.

Really, I must question your motives. What are you trying to gain? [Visual Studio Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) editions fully support WPF development, so it can't, or shouldn't, be a cost issue.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version (3.0) now supports the wpf template.

Just download it from: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/

Just type in console:

dotnet new wpf -o wpfHello

cd wpfHello

code .

Greetings :-)