# WPF desktop application without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworks

How to create WPF desktop app without using visual studio?

**I have installed only .NET Framework 4.5**, Is it possible to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @Izzy no, I do not know about it and my concept is far different, I want to just use .net framework, "no blend" or "no visual studio". Thanks

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963773/wpf-without-visual-studio

Comment: @Kishan I saw it, but I even do not want to use "Blend", how to do it? And by the way how to run one WPF app to other PC using Framework? Thanks

Comment: @NiteshKothari As the linked answer says, it is possible (even without using Blend) but not really practical. Creating the XAML without an IDE is certainly possible (in fact I hand-code all my XAML even in Visual Studio) but the hard part will be creating and maintaining the `.csproj` file that MSBuild uses to generate your executable.